# Función setInterval no se ejecuta indefinidamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

comunidad.

Tengo una función setInterval que simplemente no inicia.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('fpd-gt-next')){
    let contadorTour = document.querySelector('.fpd-gt-counter');
    let pasoContador = contadorTour.innerHTML.split("/");
    let pasoInicial = pasoContador[0];
    let cantidadPasos = pasoContador[1];
    let ventanaTour = document.querySelector('.fpd-gt-step');
    let cerrarTour = document.querySelector('.fpd-gt-back');
    let ciclo;

    if (e.target.className == 'fpd-gt-next fpd-btn fpd-primary'){
      ++pasoInicial; 
    }else if (e.target.className == 'fpd-gt-back fpd-btn fpd-primary'){
      --pasoInicial; 
    }

    if (e.target.className == 'fpd-btn fpd-primary'){
      ventanaTour.style.display = "none";
      localStorage.setItem('fpd-gt-closed', 'yes');
    }

    if (pasoInicial == cantidadPasos && ventanaTour.style.display != 'none'){
    // también intente esta linea asi: let ciclo = setInterval( function(){
    // quitando la declaración de la parte de arriba y tampoco funcionó. 
      ciclo = setInterval( function(){
      cerrarTour.innerHTML = 'Cerrar';
      cerrarTour.classList.remove('fpd-gt-back');
      clearInterval(ciclo);
      ciclo = null;
      }, 50);
    }
  }
});
```

Cuando utilizo el depurador del navegador, entra sin ningún problema al bloque de código dentro del último if cuando las condiciones están dadas, pero al resaltar la línea con el setInterval simplemente continúa el código fuera de la función y pareciera que se ejecutara una sola vez. Coloque un console.log dentro del setInterval  y aparece en la consola pero necesito que la función siga ejecutandose hasta que ce cierre la ventana emergente que contiene los elementos.

El HTML es el sigueinte:

```html
<div class="fpd-container fpd-gt-step" style="left: 55.1167px; top: 653.25px;">
  <div class="fpd-gt-pointer">
    <span class="fpd-icon-arrow-dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="fpd-gt-close">
    <span class="fpd-icon-close"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="fpd-gt-text">Paso 04</div>
  <div class="fpd-gt-actions fpd-clearfix">
    <div class="fpd-gt-next fpd-btn fpd-primary" style="display: none;">Siguiente
    </div>
    <div class="fpd-gt-back fpd-btn fpd-primary">Atras</div>
    <span class="fpd-gt-counter">4/4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

La idea es que cuando la cantidad de pasos del tourguiado sea igual al ultimo paso (4/4, por ejemplo), se  dispare el setInterval para que cambie el innerHTML del boton por "Cerrar". Lo hago con un setInterval porque al parecer tiene que ejecutarse repetidamente hasta que se cierre la ventana, de lo contario no se cambia porque ese valor lo toma el plugin de una traducción que el usuario hace desde la configuración del mismo. También debería remover la clase fpd-gt-back para que pueda cerrar la ventana pero tampoco hace eso.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Seria buena idea que colocaras tambien el HTML, el `setInterval` se ejecuta solo **1** vez ya que dentro de el tienes un `clearInterval`. Especifica un poco mas que deberia hacer el `setInterval`. saludos, estoy atento a tu respuesta :D

Comment: Es bastante extenso porque estoy modificando el código de un plugin de WordPress, pero editaré la pregunta tratando de resumir.

Comment: @Daniel Editada.

Comment: Probando el `HTML`, faltan elementos. quitando el `clearInterval` dentro del `setInterval` y añadiendo un `EventListener` al elemento que quieras que den `clic` ya podrias parar el `clearInterval`. el codigo dentro del `setInterval` no se ejecutara mas de **1** vez si no quitas dicho `clearInterval` de dentro por lo tanto debes buscar otra forma de parar el `Interval`